# Real Modulo Numbers in the Interval [0, 1), and Multiplication of

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Let's say we have a real number, A, in the interval [0, 1).
If we add another real number to it, it "Wraps" around back to zero.

So, for example:

Lets say: A = 5/13

If we multiply A by 2, we get: 10/13

If we multiple A by 3, we get: 2/13 (not 15/13)

If we multiple A by 4, we get 7/13 (not 20/13)

And so on...

My question is:

If given two such numbers, A and B, how can we find the smallest number, x, such that:

Ax = B

For example:

If A = 5/13 and B = 8/13, what do we need to multiply A by, to get B.

A solution for real numbers is preferable. However, if a solution does not exist for real numbers generally, then a solution for rational numbers should be sufficient.

Note that this problem is relevant to an algorithm that I'm writing. And I'd like to get it finished soon.

If I get my algorithm to work, and someone here provides a good solution, and that person (or people) have their name and contact details on their profile page, then I'm happy to give them a reference.

Comment: My first thought would be to see if the (extended) Euclidean algorithm would be of any use: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse

Comment: For rational numbers $a/n$ and $b/n$, this is the same as solving the congruence $ax \equiv b \pmod n$.  Solutions will not always exist (e.g., if $a = 2/4, b=1/4$).

Comment: I assumed that there was a solution with O(1), my bad. I had a look at the algorithm you suggested, and if I understand it correctly, it should work for the example above, however, it's not as efficient as I would like.